# Does the Youtube API return list of users that have watched my video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I'd like to create a [Youtube app](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) that rewards users after they have watched a certain number of my Youtube-channel's videos - or that rewards "experience points" based on the amount of time spent watching my channel.

***Can I query the Youtube API to see if an authenticated user has watched a specific video associated with the app?***

Seems like I can query against "likes" and "dislikes" - but curious if anyone has tracked "watch-time" or just "watched" in general.

My hesitation here is that I don't want access to a user's full history - I'd like a very unobtrusive approach to connecting authenticated users to specific video content.

I'm not seeing an API endpoint for querying or notifying if an associated Youtube video has been seen.  Any help you can provide would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering user privacy I don't think you can acces this information. If you search through the API, you'll find that Youtube does come with insights, like viewcount and even [demographic information](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_insight).

It might be a solution to embed your videos in your app and then track which users watch that specific video within the app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give it to you if there's no other insights - which it doesn't seem like there will be.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your app catch the the onStateChange event to log that a user viewed a video.  It will only work for video they view from inside your app.