# How to know when a user complete viewing a video with youtube api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I currently working on a project where I send a youtube video id and show it to the user. And I want to know if there are a method to know when the video is completely viewed by the user. In my application's client, I send a response to the server when the view is completed, and I want to prevent receiving falsed data from untrusted user. And that's why I want to know if youtube api make a things like that. I have seen other similar topics, but I haven't found a safe way to secure communication between client and server for this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573090/does-the-youtube-api-return-list-of-users-that-have-watched-my-video), it was mentioned that you can use `onStateChange` event to log that a user viewed a video. But the general idea here is about safety which I think is more important, from there I don't think you can do this as per the privacy of a user. You can understand more about [YouTube Reporting and Analytics here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/).